# Connect 4 Like Game

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I am making a connect four like game in python, what I have so far is creating the board and implementing game play against the computer. I am running into the issue that does not allow me to play past the second row. Any ideas on why?

```
#Define the board
row = int(input("Please enter # of rows: ")) #User input Rows
column = int(input("Please enter # of columns: ")) #User input Columns

board = [] #empty board
space = ' '
p1 = 'x'
p2 = 'o'

#create board based on user input 
for i in range(0,row):
    board.append([])
    for j in range(0, column):
        board[i].append(space)

print(board)
#print board with character decorations 
for i in board:
    line=''
    print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
    for j in range(len(i)):
        line = line + '|'+i[j]
    line = line + '|'
    print(line)
print('+'+'-+'*len(i))

print(len(board))

while True:
    #User input column
    myC = int(input("Player 1, choose your column: "))

    i = len(board)-1
    x = len(board)-1
    while i >= 0:
        if board[x][myC] == space:
            i = i+1
            board[x][myC] = 'x'
            break
        elif board[x][myC] == p1 or p2:
            i = i+1
            x = x - 1
            print(x)
            board[x][myC] = 'x'
            break

    # print the board!
    for i in board:
        line=''
        print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = line + '|'+i[j]
        line = line + '|'
        print(line)
    print('+'+'-+'*len(i))

    #Computer input column
    from random import randint
    theC = randint(0, len(board)-1)
    print("Computer's Turn: Column " , theC)

    i = len(board)-1
    x = len(board)-1
    while i >= 0:
        if board[x][theC] == space:
            board[x][theC] = 'o'
            i = i+1
            break
        elif board[x][theC] == p1 or p2:
            i = i+1
            x = x - 1
            print(x)
            board[x][theC] = 'o'
            break


    # print the board!
    for i in board:
        line=''
        print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = line + '|'+i[j]
        line = line + '|'
        print(line)
    print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured out what's going on.  Your x is always initialized to len(board)-1 and then if the space is occupied it is reduced by one.  If you make a (>2)x(>2) board and row 0 is occupied then this will always force x = 2.

This is close to correct, but what you actually need is to iterate through all rows until you find the first unoccupied row.  I created a loop that will find the first row and assign that to the value of x.  I tested it out and I'm now able to play passed 2 rows.

```
#Define the board
row = int(input("Please enter # of rows: ")) #User input Rows
column = int(input("Please enter # of columns: ")) #User input Columns

board = [] #empty board
space = ' '
p1 = 'x'
p2 = 'o'

#create board based on user input 
for i in range(0,row):
    board.append([])
    for j in range(0, column):
        board[i].append(space)

print(board)

#print board with character decorations 
for i in board:
    line=''
    print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
    for j in range(len(i)):
        line = line + '|'+i[j]
    line = line + '|'
    print(line)
print('+'+'-+'*len(i))

print(len(board))

while True:
    #User input column
    myC = int(input("Player 1, choose your column: "))

    i = len(board)-1
    x = len(board)-1
    while i >= 0:
        if board[x][myC] == space:
            i = i+1
            board[x][myC] = 'x'
            break
        # Find last empty row for new piece
        elif board[x][myC] == p1 or p2:
            for j in range(x-1,-1,-1):
                if board[j][myC] == space:
                    x = j
                    break

            i = i+1
            #x = x - 1
            print(x)
            board[x][myC] = 'x'
            break

    # print the board!
    for i in board:
        line=''
        print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = line + '|'+i[j]
        line = line + '|'
        print(line)
    print('+'+'-+'*len(i))

    #Computer input column
    from random import randint
    theC = randint(0, len(board)-1)
    print("Computer's Turn: Column " , theC)

    i = len(board)-1
    x = len(board)-1
    while i >= 0:
        if board[x][theC] == space:
            board[x][theC] = 'o'
            i = i+1
            break
        # Find last empty row for new piece
        elif board[x][theC] == p1 or p2:
            for j in range(x-1,-1,-1):
                if board[j][theC] == space:
                    x =j
                    break                
            i = i+1
            #x = x - 1
            print(x)
            board[x][theC] = 'o'
            break


    # print the board!
    for i in board:
        line=''
        print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = line + '|'+i[j]
        line = line + '|'
        print(line)
    print('+'+'-+'*len(i))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help.